# Excel Userform VBA VLOOKUP from intranet file

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a VBA Vlookup on a user form from which I would like the data to come from an excel file saved on the intranet.

When I try the `VLookup` which takes the data on the intranet, it works as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(I6,'https://intranet.private.private.uk/folder1/folder2/folder3/Documents/[Contract database.xlsm]AvailableContracts'!$H$9:$L$108,2,FALSE)
```

I would like to incorporate that link into the VBA below without getting an error message:

```
Private Sub ContractsList_AfterUpdate()

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), Me.ContractsList.Value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "This contract is not on the list"
    Me.ContractsList.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
End If
'Lookup values based on first control
With Me
    .TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ContractsList, Sheet2.Range("A5:E72"), 2, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

The line that kicks the error is:

```
.TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ContractsList, Sheet2.Range("A5:E72"), 2, 0)
```

when I change `Sheet2.Range("A5:E72")` with the intranet link above in the excel `VLookup` formula.

Comment: What error are you getting? Hard to help without knowing that. Also, what line kicks you the error?

Comment: I have added more detail to my question. Thank you

Comment: @Abigal are you going to accept as answer any of the solutions you got here ? I saw that you have plenty of question but a lot without positive feedback, this will help you get more help on SO in the future

Comment: @ShaiRado I always give feedback and appreciate the help I get with answers. I just haven't had the time to go through those answers yet. I will in due course. Thanks a million

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save a lot of time and code line using the `Application.Match`, look at the code below :

```
Private Sub ContractsList_AfterUpdate()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet

' set workbook to workbook location at internet (according to your formula)
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("https://intranet.private.private.uk/folder1/folder2/folder3/Documents/Contract database.xlsm")
Set Sht = WB.Worksheets("AvailableContracts")

With Me.ContractsList
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, Sht.Range("A:A"), 0)) Then '<-- value found in Column A
         'Lookup values based on first control
        Me.TextBox1 = Sht.Range("C" & Application.Match(.Value, Sheet2.Range("A:A"), 0)).Value
    Else '<-- value not found in Column A
        MsgBox "This contract is not on the list"
        .Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but in this scenario, match will not be faster than vlookup. The data range isn't large enough and this isn't in a loop. While I'm sure it's still technically faster, it won't be noticeable here.

Comment: Maybe, but it's better than using Countif just to find a certain match, and afterwards also a Vlookup, no ?

Comment: I agree, it is better (thus my +1), I just don't think faster is a viable reason here. I would personally do something different altogether. Worksheet functions, or match in this case, tend to give me nothing but headaches. Not sure why. Maybe I just don't use them properly.

Comment: @Shai, Thank you. this does what I want but I want to adjust it to some changes made to the "AvailableContracts" tab.

Comment: @Abigal so you should close this post, mark this as "Answer". And then open a new post, with the updated information (and updated code) and what you are trying to achieve . Otherwise, posts will never be closed, just keep accumulating new requests

Comment: "If Not Is Error(Application.Match(.Value, Sht.Range("A:A"), 0)) Then" gives me an error now, it says authomation error

Comment: @Abigal it's `IsError` one word, not `Is Error` two words

Comment: yes, that's how I have it. i did a copy and paste. Is this part of the code saying that, it looks at the contracts list and if it finds a match that is in the worksheet called available contracts, it will return data from the C column of that same worksheet?

Comment: yes, if the match was successful it do what you said, if not it pops a `MsgBox` or what you want it to do if it fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133981/discussion-between-abigal-and-shai-rado).

Answer (score 2):

The below will open the workbook and allow you to work with it like any other workbook. I updated your code to include the new workbook and the range you gave in your `VLOOKUP` from above. I don't think VBA will let you do the lookup like you are hoping.

```
Private Sub ContractsList_AfterUpdate()
Dim wb as Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("https://intranet.private.private.uk/folder1/folder2/folder3/Documents/Contract database.xlsm")
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), Me.ContractsList.Value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "This contract is not on the list"
    Me.ContractsList.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
End If
'Lookup values based on first control
With Me
    .TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ContractsList, wb.Sheets("AvailableContractsRange").Range("H9:L108"), 2, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You should determine the workbook as well.

```
 Private Sub ContractsList_AfterUpdate()

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks("Contract database").sheet2.Range("A:A"), Me.ContractsList.Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "This contract is not on the list"
            Me.ContractsList.Value = ""
        Exit Sub

        End If
        'Lookup values based on first control
        With Me

            .TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ContractsList, Workbooks("Contract database").sheet2.Range("A5:E72"), 2, 0)

        End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Vlookup does not work, because you want to refer to a different workbook, but it's not in the function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've commented out your

```
With Me
```

line, but that may just be the formatting in your question.

It would be helpful to know which error message you received.

Comment: I get a syntax error on this line:  .TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ContractsList, 'https://intranet.private.private.uk/folder1/folder2/folder3/Documents/[Contract database.xlsm]AvailableContracts'!$H$9:$L$108,2, 0)